# how do i put my own custom icon for the MDToolbar in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

How do i change the icon for the MDToolbar to my own custom icon image?

i tried to change the color the icon but it seems to not be possible, so now im looking to change it altogether. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

MDtoolbar has been removed as of v1.0 of KivyMD. You should be using MDTopAppBar instead. With MDTopAppBar you can set icons to appear on the left or right as needed.
ie.

```
MDTopAppBar:
    left_action_items: [["dots-vertical",lambda x: app.presser()]]
    right_action_items: [["account-child",lambda x: app.presser()],["hamburger",lambda x: app.presser()]]
```

See https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/toolbar/

Answer (score 0):

It Doesn't Have Any Different. You Should Use `left_action_items` or `right_action_items` and use Your own path. for example.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """
MDScreen:
    MDTopAppBar:
        pos_hint : {"top" : 1}
        left_action_items: [["YOUR PATH", lambda x: print("salam")]]
"""


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

for example you can use instead of `YOUR PATH` :

> C:\Users\YOURNAME\Desktop\answering\example.png `or` .jpg